# Ms Excel 2016 file not generating using JSP

Tags: java, excel, jsp

Am not able to export the data from a jsp to MS Excel 2016. The same code was working with previous versions. After installing 2016 it is not generating. Basically am trying to render html data to the excel.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF8" %>

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Results.xls");
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are you using tu build the XLS file ? Apache POI? Because changing the content type of the response will not transform HTML to Excel

Comment: Am not using POI. Just a jsp with content type html and css(css in the jsp itself, its not included as a file). Mainly table tags

Comment: Ok.. then the previous versions of Excel you were using was displaying HTML from a XLS file. The most probable thing is that Excel 2016 is not supporting this feature anymore. For full XLS support you should rely on a library like POI to build Excel files natively.

Comment: I know in a servlet I used to return an Excel file the type was different than the one you show: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` which specifies the .xslx file extension. (Which I'm pretty certain is the extension used primarily by Excel 2016)

Comment: I think I was super excited. I was checking across csv. Still excel is not generating with application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: Cristian Meneses, its not easy for me to go and change this. In my application there are at least 100 place where am using the same content type. It was working perfectly prior to MS 2016.

Comment: @RizwanAhmed Well, you could ask Microsoft to get that functionality back. </irony>

Comment: @JozefChocholacek thanks for your suggestion buddy. I guess, its difficult they listen me.

Comment: I got a turn around for this. Please see the below urls from Microsoft and Salesforce. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3181507 and                                                   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131404/end-user-cannot-open-a-xls-report-exported-from-salesforce Hope this helps someone.